# Do different Macs have different quality audio ADCs?

Tags: audio, hardware

I want to digitize a bunch of records from my turntable onto my Mac.  I've got a couple different Macs available with "audio in" minijacks: a Mac Pro and a Mac Mini, for example.

Do they differ in the quality of the audio they can record?  Does the Mac Pro have better ADCs or better shielding, for example?  Played back as lossless audio files to a hi-fi system, will I ever notice the difference?

Comment: tbh, if you have a *serious* record deck, then treat yourself to some high quality external USB/DACs. If not, you'd probably achieve higher sound quality by just buying the material from iTunes. I'd only go deck > mini-jack for material not easily available commercially.

Comment: Tetsujin: Thanks, but I didn't ask for the highest possible sound quality, and I don't want to spend $1000+ to buy all these albums again.  I just want to know if it makes a difference which Mac I already own has higher ADC (not DAC) quality.

Comment: Unless you already spent the $1000 on the deck, then the difference in quality of the Mac's DACs  [industry term, as they always do both tasks, they're just loosely called 'daks' rather than 'a d c's or 'd a c's]  won't really be noticeable. Just based on the general hardware quality, I'd go for the Mac Pro, though I've owned several over the past 10 years & have never actually plugged anything in those sockets, I use dedicated DACs - I'm a sound engineer by trade.

Answer (score 1):

The physical 3.5mm input jacks are likely the same or nearly identical, but the relative quality will be determined by the audio chipset used. I would check System Report on both machines, go to Audio, and see what chipsets are being used. It may not show you enough detail to know exactly which version it is, but hopefully will provide enough detail to research their respective specs online.

I wouldn't use the 3.5mm jack though. Since you have a Mac Pro you should have an on optical input available. This will be much higher resolution than the mini jack - 24bit/48k vs 16bit/44k (in most cases). Take advantage of that with something inexpensive like a Behringer UCA202 ($25 I believe.) The ADC's on it are designed for digitizing vinyl, and it has an optical out that you can connect to your Mac Pro, for the cleanest possible signal transfer to your recording software. Most people who digitize vinyl do it at 24/48 because of the added headroom it provides.

(Edit: I should have asked if your turntable's amp provides RCA outs, because that's how you would connect it to the Behringer. If it only has 3.5mm out, and you don't want to purchase a separate preamp, then your only choice would be to plug it in directly to one of your Mac's 3.5mm jacks. Just realize those are very low fidelity inputs without much amperage, so you will need to do major volume boosting in your recording software to compensate, which will introduce noise.)

Comment: Great explication.

Comment: Good idea to check System Report, but both say simply "Intel High Definition Audio".

Comment: Whichever way you go, you're going to need an RIAA pre-amp in there somewhere, otherwise you'll wonder why it sounds so weird - thin & scratchy. You also really want to work at 44.1 or multiples rather than 48, or you run the risk of introducing unnecessary quantisation steps later. 48 is a video standard, 44.1 is audio.

Comment: @Miles - yeah, pretty vague as I guessed. Still though, there's not really a compelling case to use the 3.5mm jack when you have a digital optical input available. Its resolution will blow those 3.5mm jacks out of the water. You'll need to spend a little bit of money on a spdif cable and something like the UCA202 (probably $35 in total), but it would be well worth it to be able to record at 24bit.

Comment: I've already got an RIAA pre-amp, of course, and spare optical cables.  I was hoping for some idea (via empirical test or even technical specification) of the quality of the ADC in my Macs, and it sounds like all everyone has is the *assumption* that a cheap external one ought to be better than any built-in one.  Tests of the DACs that Apple uses in the iPhone show that it's better than most external DACs, though, so I'm not confident that this assumption is warranted.

Comment: Just trying to help here mate. A 3.5mm jack is inherently noisy. Preamps are sensitive to interference and noise, so you are not going to get as good of a recording that way. Digital inputs are very low-noise, so you would introduce less overall noise into your vinyl rips this way. 

I don't think you will have much luck finding empirical tests of these intel audio chipsets for digitizing vinyl. I'm sure someone has done it, but I'm very leery of any onboard computer chipset having the kind of amp voltage necessary for boosting a preamp signal correctly without introducing undue noise.